# Does access VBA has Listbox.List method as excel VBA has

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm writing code in access vba for the list box items to move up and down. Needs to use .List Property in access . But it throws an error says no method or member found. Any replace method with .List ? Researching on this more than 4 days.
     Private Sub cmdUP_Click()

```
  Dim i As Long
 Dim leaveAlone As Boolean
 Dim pos As Long
 Dim Temp As String

pos = 0

With Me.lbfNames
For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
leaveAlone = False

If .Selected(i) Then

    If i = pos Then
    leaveAlone = True
    End If

pos = pos + 1

    If leaveAlone = False Then
    Temp = .RowSource(i - 1)
    .RowSource(i - 1) = .RowSource(i) ' before i used .List instead of rowsource
    .RowSource(i) = Temp
    .ListIndex = i - 1
    .Selected(i) = False
    .Selected(i - 1) = True
    End If

    End If
    Next

    End With
```

Comment: List boxes in Access have a `rowSource` property, maybe you should check that and manipulate it to get what you want. If your `rowSource` is an SQL instruction, then you'll need to define the way the rows are sorted in SQL.

Comment: please see my above code for moving up selected item when button clicked. In this case rowsource property is throwing exception that wrong no.of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured that out, how to do it in access. But set list box Multiselect property to 'None'.

```
 Moving Down

 Private Sub cmdDown_Click()
 Dim sText As String
 Dim iIndex As Integer
 Dim bottomLimit As Integer
 iIndex = lbfNames.ListIndex
 bottomLimit = lbfNames.ListCount - 1
 'check: only proceed if there is a selected item
 If lbfNames.ListCount > 1 Then
     If iIndex >= bottomLimit Then
        MsgBox ("Can not move the item down any further.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'save items text and items indexvalue
    sText = lbfNames.Column(0, iIndex)
    If iIndex < bottomLimit Then
        lbfNames.RemoveItem iIndex
        'place item back in new position
        lbfNames.AddItem sText, iIndex + 1
    End If
    'if you keep that item selected
    'you can keep moving it by pressing btnMoveDown
    lbfNames.Selected(iIndex + 1) = True
    iIndex = iIndex + 1
   End If
   End Sub

      Moving up

   Private Sub cmdUP_Click()     
   Dim sText As String
   Dim iIndex As Integer
   iIndex = lbfNames.ListIndex
 ' ReDim iIndex(0 To 10)
  'check: only proceed if there is a selected item
   If lbfNames.ListCount > 1 Then
    'index 0 is top item which can't be moved up!
    If iIndex <= 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Can not move the item up any higher.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' If iIndex = -1 Or lbfNames.ListCount > 1 Then
    'save items text and items indexvalue
    sText = lbfNames.Column(0, iIndex)
    lbfNames.RemoveItem iIndex
    'place item back on new position
    lbfNames.AddItem sText, iIndex - 1
    'if you keep that item selected
    'you can keep moving it by pressing cmdUp
    lbfNames.Selected(iIndex - 1) = True
    iIndex = iIndex - 1
    End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: No, MS Access VBA doesn't have `ListBox.List(row, column)` but instead it has `ListBox.AddItem(Item, Index)` and `ListBox.RemoveItem(Index)`

For Multi-Column ListBoxes semi-colon character ';' could be used to separate column items i.e. `myMultiColListBox.AddItem("Col_1_item;Col_2_item;Col_3_item")`